# IPhone - code sign, provisioning, certificate

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm trying to generate an IPA file for test in some devices, but when I try to install in these devices with IPhone Configuration Utility, I receive this message: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found ".

I double-checked the certificate and provisioning(distribution), the Project-> Build Settings -> Code Signing and Target -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity are correct too.

Something that I realised is when I try Archive -> Share, the Identity has no valid provisioning profile (look at the picture):

[Valid XHTML http://tlab.in/codesign.png](http://tlab.in/codesign.png).

I googled all the day and I couldn't find anything that would help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are common issues that you should review:

1. In your Provisioning Portal (in the Apple Developer site), make sure to have **Distribution** tab a valid and **Active** Distribution Provisioning Profile, and it should be of type AdHoc.
2. Make sure that you have added the device ID into the profile of step 1.
3. Make sure that you have written the correct **Bundle Identifier** in your project (the one that says com.yourcompany.yourproject)
4. Check that you have set in Xcode the Build Settings->Code Signing->Release to the correct identifier.
5. After these steps you should be able to press on the combobox of the image you provided and select the AdHoc certificate.
6. Sometimes you might need to manually delete old Provisioning Profiles from the devices that you are testing (from Settings->General->Profiles).

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is no valid AdHoc provisioning profile for the bundle ID that you assigned to the application.  If you are going to create an IPA to share - it needs to be an AdHoc profile - and be sure that bundle ID matches.